# The question of quasi-isometry

Tags: geometric-group-theory

I cannot show the following quetion.

"Let X and Y be metric spaces , and f: X → Y be a quasi-isometry.Show that there exists a finite metric space Z and a map F: X × Z → Y which is also a quasi-isometry and is onto."

If f is onto , this question is clear.
So, the problem is the case that f is not onto.

Please advice to me

Comment: Maybe "finite" means bounded?

Comment: I think so . First, I thought that "finite" means that the factor of the set is finite ,but for this idea this is not true by the answer of Mr.user111ooo

Comment: The answer is positive for bounded sets. However, this sounds like a homework, in which case you need to show an attempt on doing it yourself and show where are you stuck. For instance, could you do it in the case of integers embedded in the real line?

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this is an exercise in a text ,not a homework. In case of integers embedded in the real line , inclusion map $\mathbb{Z}$ → $\mathbb{R}$ is a quasi-isometry.So, Z= $\mathbb{R}$/$\mathbb{Z}$ is defined.Then,Z is bounded set,and F is surjective quasi-isometry .

Comment: More precisely, Z= $\mathbb{R}$/f($\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: What would you use as the map $F$ in this example? My point is that a very similar argument will work in general.

Comment: F(x,[z]) = f(x) + [z] where x $\in$$\mathbb{Z}$ [z] $\in$ Z

Comment: Is this idea wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proof in the case where "finite metric space" means "bounded metric space", as in your comments.

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a quasi-isometry. Define the metric space $Z$ to be the set $Y$ equipped with the discrete metric taking only the values $0$ and $1$. Since $f$ is a quasi-isometry, there exists a constant $R$ so that 
$$
\bigcup_{x\in X} B(f(x), R)= Y,
$$
where $B(y,R)$ is the (closed) metric $R$-ball in $Y$ centered at $y$. Now, 
for each $y\in Y$ there exists a surjective map $g_y: Z\to B(y, R)$, since cardinality of $Z$ is greater than (or equal to) cardinality of $B(y, R)$. Then define the map 
$$
F: X\times Z\to Y
$$ 
by sending each $(x, z)$ to $g_{f(x)}(z)$. By construction, $F$ is surjective.

Let us check that $F$ is a quasi-isometry. Note that the map $F$ is within distance $R$ from the map
$$
f\circ p : X\times Z\to Y 
$$
where $p(x,z)=x$. Since both $p$ and $f$ are quasi-isometries, so is $F$. qed

Comment: Sorry,but one question is that in the concrete $g_y$ (z)=?? for each z $\in$Z

Comment: This is an existence theorem, coming from comparing cardinalities. If you want, the map $Z=Y\to B(y,R)$ is the nearest-point projection.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you for helping me .

Answer (score 2):

This is not true, at least for the definition of [quasi-isometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry) that I'm familiar with. The inclusion map $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R$ is a quasi-isometry. Multiplying $\mathbb Z$ by a finite (or countable) metric space gives another countable space, which of course cannot be mapped onto $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Your idea is correct. So, let "finite" mean that there exists a constant R>0 such that d(x,y) < R for x,y$\in$ Z . In this case, is the question true ?